# Generic Number Add Function

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I wanted to create a generic function in kotlin language that will add all types of Numbers i.e. Double, Float, Long, Int, Byte, Char, Short. So I have created a function :

```
fun <T : Number> add (a: T, b: T) = a + b
```

But Android Studio IDE throwing compile time error on `+` sign as `Number` class doesn't have `plus` method. Why is that? And can someone please provide solution for generic function in `kotlin` without using `if else` or `when` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Your function only knows that they are both Numbers unless you check their types and cast. There is no `Number.plus(Number)` function so you can't add them as is. You can instead convert them to Doubles and add those, since there is a `Number.toDouble()` function. The type does not need to be reified.

```
fun <T : Number> add (a: T, b: T) = a.toDouble() + b.toDouble()
```

Comment: What if  params `a` and `b` are Int then why should I convert them to double?

Comment: You said you didn't want a `when` statement. If you want to keep them as Ints, you would need a `when` statement to treat that specific case (where they are both Ints) separately.

Comment: What's the solution with the when clause? And why do we not need to be reified?

Comment: @SriKrishna, there's no need to reify since all the types we care about here would be final types. You can check if the number is an Int with `is Int` and know for sure it isn't some subclass of `Int`. And there is no supertype of `Int` you could need to know about either since there is no type between `Number` and `Int` in the hierarchy.

Comment: To do this with `when`, you could do `when (this) { is Int -> { /*something*/ }, is Float -> {/*something*/ }` and so on. But what I didn't mention in the answer is that if you are doing something like this, it is a very big code smell. In 13 years of Java and Kotlin programming, I have never encountered a valid use case for trying to work with the `Number` interface to do math.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above suggestion and created a sample code for testing the requirement, check the below code, which can be pasted in a scratch or in a Kotlin Playground to run and test.

```
fun main() {
    println("Calculating the Sum of an Array")
    (1..5).toList().customSumAll { sum ->
        println("The Sum of the Array is $sum")
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Number> List<T>.customSumAll(h: (T) -> Unit) {
    var sum : T = getZeroByType()
    println("Zero Value of Type ${T::class} is $sum")
    for (item in this) {
        println("item is $item")
        sum = sum.plus(item) as T
    }
    h(sum)
}

inline fun <reified T> getZeroByType(): T {
    return when (T::class) {
        Long::class, Int::class, Short::class, Byte::class, Double::class, Float::class -> 0 as T
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown numeric type")
    }
}

operator fun Number.plus(other: Number): Number {
    return when (this) {
        is Long -> this.toLong() + other.toLong()
        is Int -> this.toInt() + other.toInt()
        is Short -> this.toShort() + other.toShort()
        is Byte -> this.toByte() + other.toByte()
        is Double -> this.toDouble() + other.toDouble()
        is Float -> this.toFloat() + other.toFloat()
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown numeric type")
    }
}

main()
```

See screenshot of the code execution:

[image: Ran the code in a Scratch in Android Studio]